# Calculating average from a file gives unexpected output

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to java and I wonder why this code is not giving the desire result. I have to read a text file with the following format:

```
Name Last Name, 92 82 88 96 78
name Last Name, 87 93 85 82 94
```

Basically name + last name, and then 5 scores. I need to read the file and print to the console the name follow by the average of each person scores. The number of scores will always be 5 but the number of persons it is not specified. My code throws a `NoSuchElementException` and gives me wrong results for the averages. Take a look:

```
package nameavgfile;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class NameAvgFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile;
        final int count = 5;
        double score = 0;
        try{
            inFile = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
                String name = inFile.next()+" "+inFile.next();
                while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){
                    score += inFile.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(name+" "+score/count);
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1:

You're not resetting the score to zero when you start a new line.

Move this line:

```
double score = 0;
```

to the first line inside the outer (line) loop.

#### Problem 2:

You're printing the average every time you read a score. Instead, print the average *after* you've read all the scores, so move this line:

```
System.out.println(name+" "+score/count);
```

outside the inner (score) loop to the last line of the outer (line) loop.

#### Problem 3:

You're not consuming the new line characters after the scores. Add this line to the end of your loop:

```
inFile.nextLine();
```

---

Java 8 has some stuff that can make this task easier. Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("c:/tmp/data.txt")).forEach(NameAvgFile::processLine);
}

private static void processLine(String line) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    System.out.println(parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + sum(Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 2, parts.length)));
}

private static double sum(String[] doubleStrings) {
    return Arrays.stream(doubleStrings).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).average().getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: You had my upvote until that incomprehensible mess at the bottom.

Comment: @ILMTitan you're absolutely right... in my desire to achieve a one-line solution, I ignored the "good code is readable" mantra and instead created a train wreck. I've refactored it to be IMHO readable (still keeping the good bits of java 8). You were right to call me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try just to put `System.out.println(name+" "+score/count);` inside the first loop like below:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner inFile;
      final int count = 5;
       double score = 0;
       try{
           inFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp\\file.txt"));
           while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
                String name = inFile.next()+" "+inFile.next();
                while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){
                     score += inFile.nextDouble(); 
                }
                System.out.println(name+" "+score/count);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```